# openright sections in article class

Tags: sectioning, article

Is there a way to achieve something like `openright`, but for sections in the article class?

The MWE would be somthing like this, real simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Number 1}
Some text...
\section{Number 2}
Some text...
\section{Number 3}
Some text...
\section{Number 4}
Some text...

\end{document}
```

But every section should start on the right page.

Comment: To be frank, if you want to start sections on a new (odd) page, you dhould really consider using `report` (or something like that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very likely you are using the wrong class.

Nevertheless, `\cleardoublepage` can be added before each `\section`. Also class option `twoside` needs to be set:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\section{\cleardoublepage}{}%
  {\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\section failed}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Number 1}
Some text...
\section{Number 2}
Some text...
\section{Number 3}
Some text...
\section{Number 4}
Some text...

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, I should have used the report class, but I'm rather new to latex and I decided that this way looked better after printing and then it was too late to change all the sectioning in the entire document, but this helped me and saved me lots of time. Thank you!!